# Filtering a promise array

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

```
if (filterLabel) {
result = result.filter((r) =>
  (r.labels).map((l) => l.name === filterLabel));}
```

The Error is "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<Label[]>'".

How can I filter this array? filterlabel is a name of a Label like "Test1"

```
export class Task {
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@Column()
name: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@Column()
description: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@CreateDateColumn()
created: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@UpdateDateColumn()
updated: string;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@ManyToMany(() => Label, (label) => label.tasks)
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@JoinTable()
labels: Promise<Label[]>;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@OneToMany(() => Tracking, (tracking) => tracking.task, {nullable: true})

trackings: Promise<Tracking[]>;
```

}

```
export const getAllTasks = async (req, res) => {
const taskRepository = getRepository(Task);
const tasks = await taskRepository.find(
  {relations: ['trackings', 'labels']});

 const {filterTask, filterDescription, filterLabel} = req.query;
 console.log('1', filterTask, '2', filterDescription, '3', filterLabel, 
 '4');
 let result = [...tasks];

 if (filterTask) {
 result = result.filter((r) => r.name === filterTask);
 }
 if (filterLabel) {
  filter();
 }
 if (filterDescription) {
   result = result.filter((d) => d.description === filterDescription);
 }
  res.status(200).send({data: result});
 };
```

How can i Filter for labels? I dont understand it.
The other filters are right but the label filter is bad because of the promises

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```js
 let result = [{ labels: Promise.resolve([{name: "Name1"}, {name: "Name2"}])},{labels: Promise.resolve([{name: "Name3"}, {name: "Name4"}])},];

const filterLabel = "Name2";

const filter = async () => {
  let items = [];
  for(let r=0; r< result.length; r++) {
    const labels = await result[r].labels;
    for(let l=0; l< labels.length; l++) {
      const label = labels[l];
      if(label.name === filterLabel) {
        items.push(result[r]);
        break;
      };
    }
  }
  console.log(items, items.length);
}

filter();
```

Comment: I've tried reverse engineering the data structure but there is no real easy way of both preserving it and filtering at the same time. Any filtering operation will pend until that inner promise gets settled. So, *at best*, the code needs to wait for that to happen, then re-construct the `results` array but replace `labels` with the resolved data and also filter it. It's doable but way more hassle than perhaps needed. If it's *just* the labels it's easier but it's still quite confusing overall: https://tsplay.dev/Qmbb8m

Comment: Yes, sure, what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: For example with this line result = result.filter((r) =>
  (r.labels).map((l) => l.name === filterLabel));}, what is your desire result, for example result = [{???}];

Comment: @VLAZ a have a new post. there is my problem better described.can you show there?